# Selenium Join non selenium based web session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to start browsing manually in Chrome and, after reaching a certain point, start a python selenium routine that can access and take over the previously started chrome session? I have read through what's been posted and I don't seem to see this specific question asked and answered.

Thanks.

Comment: No.  The browser would need to be launched in debug/dev mode to have a port or sessionID to attach to.